# How to report a binom.test

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, reporting

How do I properly report the results of an R language `binom.test` ([see documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/binom.test.html)). My target is the APA format.

Also, I am not sure whether the proper name of the test is "Exact Binomial Test" or whether it has another name.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Found. In this link SPSS Binomial Test - Beginners Tutorial https://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-binomial-test/ you can see how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binomial test is also known as a test of proportions. The hypothesis is  that the proportion equals some value $p = p_0$. The term "exact" also distinguishes this test from its better known counterpart, taught in most elementary statistics classes, of the normal approximation to the proportion. by calculating the Score statistic: $T = (p-p_0)/\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)/n}$. We prefer exact tests because we actually know the distribution of $\hat{p}$ when the null hypothesis is true, so we can calculate the p-value from that, and there is no large sample requirement.

A significant two tailed test indicates evidence that the proportion is different from the null hypothesized value of $p_0$.

Comment: Thank you! That was very useful. I guess then that what I should report in this case is the p-value and the empirical proportion, apart from the true population proportion.

Comment: @FranciscoQV well you don't know the true population proportion, that's why you gathered these data. Report the proportion, then give a 95% CI for the value.

Comment: I think "binomial test" is less ambiguous than "test of proportions".

Comment: @FranciscoQV, yes, you should report the empirical proportion, the expected proportion, and the p-value.  You probably should also report the total count of observations.  Also, you'll note that the binom.test function reports a confidence interval for the proportion *.  Depending on your application, the confidence interval may be more useful for the reader than the p-value. | * Clopper-Pearson method.